# How do I escape parentheses and brackets in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to escape parentheses and brackets in a short Ruby script. The script takes the name of the directory as an argument, makes a playlist of the .mp3s in the directory, and names the playlist from the directory.

If the directory has braces or parentheses, it fails without an error, it just doesnt make the playlist. Here is the code:

```
  1 #!/usr/bin/ruby -w
  2 
  3 # create a playlist for a specified directory of .mp3 files
  4 
  5 puts "enter path to album:"
  6 chomped = gets.chomp
  7 path = File.expand_path("#{chomped}")
  8 
  9 data = "#EXTM3U\n"
 10 tracks = Dir["#{path}/*.mp3"]
 11 name = path.sub(/.*\/(.*)/,"\\1")
 12 name.gsub!(/_/," ")
 13 name.gsub!(/(\A|\s)\w/) { |c| c.upcase }
 14 tracks.sort.each do |track|
 15     track_name = track.sub(/.*\/(.*)/,"\\1")
 16     data += "#EXTINF:\n" + track_name + "\n"
 17 end
 18 File.open("#{path}/#{name}.m3u","a") { |f| f.write data }
 19 puts "created #{path}/#{name}.m3u"
```

I have been able to escape the underscores, and I think I got a regex working to escape the other characters, (http://rubular.com/r/BNUnjSde6J) but it still fails using `.gsub!`. Also, I would rather not escape them, I'd like the title to include them. Would `Regexp.escape` be an answer?

EDIT: to clarify, the tracknames need not be full paths because the playlist will reside in the same directory as the tracks themselves. see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U

Comment: Could you please give an example of a track_name string and what you want the result of the regex to be?

Comment: You should include filenames/directory names as an example, possibly, it's not entirely clear what your script chokes on.

Comment: thanks guys, an example of a track would be "home/user/Music/Artist/Album (2011) [MP3]/01 Name of Song.mp3" and a directory would be "home/user/Music/Artist/Album (2011) [MP3]". i want the song name to be "01 Name of Song.mp3" (this seems to work fine) and the album (which is gotten with lines 5-7) to be "Album (2011) [MP3]". the album should be the name of the playlist as well. the regex im using to get rid of [] and () is "\[^()[\]]\", which is working with the above link. im lost without it giving me an error, the playlist just never gets created.

Comment: because the playlist is inside the directory that the tracks are. so when opening the m3u it looks at the directory that it is already in for the files.

Comment: @rick: Put that in the question, not in the comments section. Else we're going to give you up, and let you down.

Comment: @Andrew will do. afterall, i just wanna tell you how i'm feeling. gotta make you understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should work:

```
escaped_path = path.gsub(/([\[\]\{\}\*\?\\])/, '\\\\\1')
tracks = Dir["#{escaped_path}/*.mp3"]
```

I determined the characters that needed to be escaped by looking at the API for [Dir.glob](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Dir.html#M000629). The regular expression is complicated because the same characters are also used in regular expressions!

Separate to your parentheses problem, you have a bigger issue. You're basically re-writing the m3u file over and over like [Schlemiel the Painter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter%27s_algorithm). Better to open the file handle outside of the track loop instead.

Comment: do you suggest that because it would create the file if it doesn't exist? EDIT: gotcha. re-working it now.

Comment: @rick: I've updated the answer with a solution to your original problem - hope it helps.

Comment: Schlemiel the Painter wikipedia link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter's_algorithm

Comment: @Andrew: Isn't there a rule that you have to read the collected works of Joel Spolsky before joining this site? :P

Comment: thank you, this is great. also, "a methodology that is inefficient because the programmer has overlooked some fundamental issues at the very lowest levels of software design." BURN. haha. thanks again.